# Нахождение производной функции на Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, математика

Я считываю `func` как строку, затем же мне надо найти производную функции, записанной в переменной `func`. Например: пусть `func = "3*x**2 - 5*x"`, тогда итогом должна быть строка `"6*x-5"`. Помогите пожалуйста с реализацией этого. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Если входные функции только обычные многочлены, то всё достаточно тривиально - парсим строку, делим её на члены, выделяем коэффициент и степень и применяем правила нахождения производной. Но если нужно решение для произвольной функции - то тут уже вряд ли возможно что-то придумать.

Answer (score 2):

Проще всего воспользоваться библиотекой [sympy](https://www.sympy.org/)

```py
import sympy

func = '3*x**2 - 5*x'
print(sympy.diff(func)) # 6*x - 5
```

Но она не идеальная, и с некоторыми уравнениями может не справиться.